# org-babel not concatenating strings before sending to code block variable

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-table

I have just started using org-mode and org-babel as a lab notebook. I am trying to use a code block to fill in two columns of a table. The code block seems to work for the first column because those are the right numbers. However, when trying to concatenate a string to the file name in column three so the code blocks works on a different set of files it seems to just run the code block on the original files instead, which produces the same output as column one.

```
#+name: tRNAs
#+begin_src sh :var filename="" :results silent
cd Data/tRNA
grep -c ">" $filename
#+end_src


#+tblname: sequences
| # of Sequences before QC | # after QC | Original File name|
|--------------------------+------------+------------------|
|                   681865 |     681865 | read1            |
|                   324223 |     324223 | read2            |
|                  1014578 |    1014578 | read3            |
|                   971965 |     971965 | read4            |
|                   931777 |     931777 | read5            |
|                   810798 |     810798 | read6            |
|                   965134 |     965134 | read7            |
|                   718474 |     718474 | read8            |
|--------------------------+------------+------------------|
#+TBLFM: $1='(org-sbe tRNAs (filename (concat "\"" $3 "\"")))
#+TBLFM: $2='(org-sbe tRNAs (filename (concat "\"final_" $3 "\"")))
```

Comment: It would be good to post an example that is simple and self-contained so others can run it and provide better answers.

Comment: @mankoff Sorry about that. You can recreate the environment by having files named read1...read8 and final_read1....final_read8 with variable numbers of ">" characters.

Comment: @Darwin - What version of Emacs & org-mode are you using?

Comment: @Melioratus I am using Org-mode version 8.2.10 and Aquamacs 3.2a which uses GNU Emacs 24.4.51.2

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one `#+TBLFM` line per table. Separate formula with "::". Does it work if you have the following?

```
#+TBLFM: $1='(org-sbe tRNAs (filename (concat "\"" $3 "\"")))::$2='(org-sbe tRNAs (filename (concat "\"final_" $3 "\"")))
```

Comment: The above doesn't work and `#+TBLFM: $1='(org-sbe tRNAs (filename (concat "\"" $3 "\"")))::$2='(org-sbe tRNAs (filename (concat "\"final_" $3 "\"")))` does not work either. It seems like you can have more than one `#+TBLFM` line per table you just have to `^C-^C` each one.

Comment: @Darwin - just to clarify, you're saying it is possible to have more than one `#+TBLFM:` line but the user must move their cursor to each line then do `C-c C-c`? Does `concat` work on line 1 and not line 2?

Comment: @Melioratus - Yes, I can have more than one `#+TBLFM:` line, but you need to `C-c C-c` each one. The `concat` does work with the first one. I have created another column with the filename I tried to create with `concat` and just `concat` the `"` marks like the first formula. Now both work.